# Manually installing sample schemas in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, schema

I am trying to manually install HR schema in my oracle environment by following the steps specified by oracle Help Center (11.2). Web link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC001
However, I have run into some problems. It is specified that I only need to call `hr_main.sql` script (located in `human_resources` directory)using this command `@?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql`.
 
My `human_resources` has only a script named `hr_code` and when I run it I do not get any type of installation procedure (entering password, tablespace etc as oracle specifies in the procedure). 
Any help as well as other possible solutions would be very much appreciated. 
Alternatively, could it be more feasible if I created a new database using database configuration assistant (thus installing the schemas during the installation procedure itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manually Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#I4367)

> Install **Oracle Database Examples (Companion CD, part of the media kit)**
>   to include these scripts in the demo directory under $ORACLE_HOME.

The scripts for installing sample schemas is a seperate download and they are not installed by default.

[Download Oracle Database Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24501/toc.htm#BABBIBJF)

Follow the instructions there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I am following it, but the oracle link to download Oracle Database Examples zip file (from [link]http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) is broken.

Comment: @Bendemann The link here is not broken: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has them on GitHub.

https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

They also have the scripts for LiveSQL userd.